# nodejs - How to Loop Through Keys in JSON String & Calc

Tags: json, node.js, loops, parsing

I am trying to make a little nodejs ticker for calculating market cap. There are about 1500 entries. I want to loop through them, and sum up the values. Currently stuck on the loop

**JSON URL**

```
https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=10
```

**Current Code**

```
const https = require("https");
const url =
  "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/";

https.get(url, res => {
  res.setEncoding("utf8");
  let body = "";
  res.on("data", data => {
    body += data;
  });
  res.on("end", () => {
    body = JSON.parse(body);

    console.log(
      `Coin: ${body[0].id} -`,
      `Marketcap: ${body[0].market_cap_usd}`
    );

   //Loop through body results, sum up body[key].market_cap_usd
   //console.log(total_sum)
  });
});
```

**Current Output**

```
Coin: bitcoin - Marketcap: 149563018605
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `let totalMarketCap = body.reduce((p,c,i,a) => { return p += c.market_cap_usd; }, 0);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reduce` is your friend:

```
const https = require("https");
const url =
  "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/";

https.get(url, res => {
  res.setEncoding("utf8");
  let body = "";
  res.on("data", data => {
    body += data;
  });
  res.on("end", () => {
    body = JSON.parse(body);

    console.log(
      `Coin: ${body[0].id} -`,
      `Marketcap: ${body[0].market_cap_usd}`
    );

    const total_sum = body.reduce((sum, item) => sum + Number(item.market_cap_usd), 0)
    console.log(total_sum)
  });
});
```